# How do I reuse paintings in a Qt widget

Tags: qt

During a paint event,  How can I reuse previous paintings so that I can just paint on top of the previous result.  Right now the whole rendering area needs repainting.

gonna try QPixmap.

Do I absolutely need to use update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to cache the painting in a `QImage` or `QPixmap` (probably a `QPixmap`).  If you do this a lot, you might also want to look at `QPixmapCache`.

Additionally, a lot of drawing can be calculated beforehand, then fairly quickly done using `QPainterPath`s.  I will often use them and recalculate when necessary, rather than caching the whole paint event in a pixmap.

**Edit:**

I also ran into a brief mention of [QPicture](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qpicture.html), which might also be something you want to look at:

> The QPicture class is a paint device that records and replays QPainter commands.

Comment: Make sure that you use the integer based interface of the pixmap cache and not the old string based one (added in 4.6).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid instantiating variables in the paintEvent() you could make them member variables - this includes the QPainter object. You only need to call update() when you need the widget to repaint itself.

Why do you not want to just repaint it from scratch? Is this some kind of premature optimization, or have you noticed slow-down?

Comment: Havent noticed a slowdown, doing it for optimization.

Comment: after completing my paintEvent I see that it is less complicated to just repaint the whole thing everytime